# sub query and inner join in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

i wrote 2 queries one is with sub-query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT pp.employeeid
FROM payment pp JOIN Employee e
ON e.employeeid = pp.employeeid WHERE pp.employeeid IN 
(SELECT employeeid 
FROM employee
WHERE branchid IN 
(SELECT branchid 
FROM branch
WHERE code IN 
(SELECT code 
FROM bank p 
WHERE code = 15)));
GO
```

and other is with inner join query

```
    select DISTINCT pp.employeeid from payment pp inner join employee e 
on e.employeeid=pp.employeeid
inner join branch b on b.branchid=e.branchid
inner join bank br on br.code=b.code
where br.code=15
```

Here both queries return same data and i want to ask which one is more suitable ? and which one is preferred to use..

Comment: The inner join is much more readable, and at a guess I would think it is quicker looking at what it has to do.

Comment: Better use JOIN. Compare query plans, probably they are similar, may be not

Answer (score 0):

**Joins VS Subqueries:**

You can use to query data from different tables and might share the same result, but there are a bunch of differences in between. Knowing the differences and when to use either a join or Subquery to reach your data will be your success. =)

**Joins:**
Is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

**Subquery:**
Is also called an inner query or inner select, while the statement containing a subquery is also called an outer query or outer select. [Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx)

I prefer Joins for this kind of operation, is even easier to read:

```
select DISTINCT pp.employeeid 
from payment pp inner join employee e on e.employeeid=pp.employeeid
inner join branch b on b.branchid=e.branchid
inner join bank br on br.code=b.code
where br.code=15
```